# Can the Nc3+e3 Chebanenko Slav, the Exchange Slav and the 4...Bg4 Slow Slav transpose into each other?

Tags: opening, theory, 1.d4, slav-defense, transpositions

I would like to know if the following three variations can transpose into each other?

- The Nc3+e3 Chebanenko Slav: 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e3 a6
- The Exchange Slav: 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. cxd5 cxd5
- The 4...Bg4 Slow Slav: 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3 Bg4

?

I'm asking because:

- 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e3 a6 5. Nf3 b5 6. cxd5 cxd5 looks like an Exchange Slav
- 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. e3 a6 5. Nf3 b5 6. b3 Bg4 looks like a 4...Bg4 Slow Slav.
- 1. d4 d5 2. c4 c6 3. Nf3 Nf6 4. e3 Bg4 5. cxd5 looks like an Exchange Slav.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't transpose to Exchange Slavs.

In the Slow Slav and the Chebanenko, white plays e3 to prevent trouble with the c4 pawn. The bishop stays inside the pawn chain which is somewhat passive, but the plus is that c4 is defended, so that black can't stir up trouble by taking it and defending it with ...b5.

In the Exchange, white has dealt with that issue drastically by just exchanging the pawn away, so there's no need to make further concessions because of threats to it. I've never seen an Exchange Slav where white chose to keep Bc1 inside the chain, it goes to f4.